# A program to send an image file from client to server in python using TCP

Tags: python, sockets

This is my code. Currently it transfers about 75% of the image file (cropped at the bottom). I want it transferred as a whole. This is how I've been working on it:

1. Create a folder in server pc called "server"
2. Create a folder in client pc called "client"
3. Also include the image file you want to transfer in the same "client" folder
4. Client side ask "name of the file you want to send", I type in the name of the image file in the folder
5. Aerver side ask me "name of the file you want to receive", I type any random name.
6. The file transfers and gets saved to "server" folder in the server PC.

**`client.py`**

```
from socket import *

def establish_connection(server_IP, server_port):
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((server_IP, server_port))
    return client_socket

def send_recv_message(client_socket, message, buffer_size):
    file = open(filename,'rb')
    file_data = file.read(buffer_size)
    client_socket.send(file_data)
    text=print("File transfered")
    return text



server_IP = input("Please, enter server IP address: ")
server_port = input("Please, enter server TCP connection port number: ")
client_socket = establish_connection(server_IP, int(server_port))
print("Connection established\n")



filename= input(str("enter filename"))

received_message = send_recv_message(client_socket,filename,1048576)
```

**`server.py`**

```
from socket import *

def create_socket(server_port):
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('', server_port))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    return server_socket


def recv_message(server_socket, buffer_size):
    file = open(filename, 'wb')
    connection_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    file_data= connection_socket.recv(buffer_size)
    file.write(file_data)
    file.close()
    text=("file recieved")
    return text


server_port = input("Please, enter TCP connection port number: ")
server_socket = create_socket(int(server_port))

while (True):
    filename=input(str("enter filename for the incoming file:"))
    incoming_message = recv_message(server_socket,  1048576)
    print ("{}" .format(incoming_message))
```

Comment: Well, you're only calling `file_data = file.read(buffer_size)` once.  What happens if the filesize is larger than the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

`send` may not send the entire buffer. You need to use `sendall` instead.

`recv` may not receive all the available data. You need to call `recv` in a loop until the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the picture is more than the buffer size.
you have to send the size of the pic form client to server..example for text sending this can be used for image to...

## eg

```
 send_message = input()
```

mess = f'{len(send_message)}'.ljust(buffer_size) + send_message
soc.send(mess.encode())

at the server side find the size of picture and while size is not equal to your message recieved keep appending the msg.

```
  message = ''
    mes_len = 0
    new_msg = True
    print('got the connection: {}'.format(self.request))
    while True:
        data = self.request.recv(buffer_size)
        if new_msg:
            mes_len = int(data.decode())
            new_msg = False
        message += data.decode()
```